# C++11: condition variable only works for once

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization

I have this piece of code:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
for(;;)
{
    // wait for input notification
    m_event.wait(lock);

    // if there is an input pin doesn't have any data, just wait
    for(DataPinIn* ptr:m_in_ports)
        if(ptr->m_data_dup==NULL)
            continue;

    // do work
    Work(&m_in_ports,&m_out_ports);

    // this might need a lock, we'll see
    for(DataPinIn* ptr:m_in_ports)
    {
        // reduce the data refcnt before we lose it
        ptr->FreeData();
        ptr->m_data_dup=NULL;
        std::cout<<"ptr:"<<ptr<<"set to 0\n";
    }
}
```

in which **m_event** is a **condition_variable**.
It waits for notification from another thread and then does some works. But I found out that this only succeeds for the first time and it blocks on **m_event.wait(lock)** forever, no matter how many times **m_event.notify_one()** is called. How should I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the common scenario 'spurious wakeup' (please consult wiki) which condition_variable is desgined to solve.

Please read the sample code in this article: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/.

Usually condition_variable must be used together with a certain variable to avoid spurious wakeups; that's how the synchronization method is named.

Below is a better piece of sample code:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::queue<int> produced_nums;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;
    bool done = false;
    bool notified = false;

    std::thread producer([&]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            std::cout << "producing " << i << '\n';
            produced_nums.push(i);
            notified = true;
            cond_var.notify_one();
        }   

        done = true;
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }); 

    std::thread consumer([&]() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        while (!done) {
            while (!notified) {  // loop to avoid spurious wakeups
                cond_var.wait(lock);
            }   
            while (!produced_nums.empty()) {
                std::cout << "consuming " << produced_nums.front() << '\n';
                produced_nums.pop();
            }   
            notified = false;
        }   
    }); 

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
}
```

Comment: Thank you nim. In fact, I just found out this happens because my wait misses the notification. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a flag variable ruined everything and the threading part is working correctly.

Comment: Okay, it seems my answner is an overkill. But I still suggest you use a boolean variable to guard against spurious wakeups as the sample code shows.